# Javascript - submit button fails to call form action

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi i simplified my register form as it wasn't calling the form action when the button was click. Now the form on contains a submit button, yet it still fails to call the action of the form. I can't see where there could be any problems. Thanks in advance for your help.

Form:

```
<div id="test"> 
             <form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="test.php" >
             <input type="submit" />
             </form>
        </div>
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

Comment: Based on the code above, it should work.  Is it the only form on your page?  Do you have any JavaScript code running?

Comment: The page contains just this form. I have a javascript function at the top but it never called. Do you want me to show the whole page?

Comment: Sorry guy. move a piece of <script> and it works. Sorry about that. But it works now.